# Questions on GLM: General Language Model Pretraining with Autoregressive Blank Infilling

Tags: nlp, autoencoder

For [GLM: General Language Model Pretraining with Autoregressive Blank Infilling](https://aclanthology.org/2022.acl-long.26.pdf#page=3) ,

1. May I ask how is the sampling for input division in step (b) being done ?
2. why in step (c), the green `x3` is moved to the end ? why is the maximum value in `Position 1` limited to 5 instead of 6 ?
3. why Part A tokens cannot attend to Part B tokens ? but Part B tokens can attend to A ?

[image: GLM]

Answer (score 0):

1. The sampling strategy is described in Section 2.1. Specifically, we design three different sampling strategies for different types of downstream tasks.
2. The order of [x5, x6] and [x3] is randomly shuffled. Position 1 represents the position in the corrupted text and there are only 5 tokens in the corrupted text
3. The model needs to predict the tokens in Part B. If tokens in Part A can attend to tokens in Part B, the model can obtain the information from the representations of Part A.